# Magento 2 CSS do not loading in Backend

Tags: magento2, css

I am beginner in magento 2, I want to add a style CSS for my Block but it does not work, here is the code:

```
 <head>
    <css src="Managys_Pricing::css/style.css"/>
</head>
<update handle="editor"/>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Managys\Pricing\Block\Adminhtml\Configuration\Edit" name="pricingadmin_configuration_edit"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="left">
        <block class="Managys\Pricing\Block\Adminhtml\Configuration\Edit\Tabs" name="pricingadmin_configuration_edit_tabs"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

At the level of Block\Adminhtml\Configuration\Edit\Tab I added column_css_class

```
$fieldset
        ->addField(
            'date_update',
            'label',
            [
                'label' => __("Dernière mise à jour des prix   :"    .$configuration["last_price_update"]),
                'column_css_class' => 'date_update'
            ]

        );
```

And I put in the css file,

```
.date_update{
width: 500px;
 }
```

[image]

I do not know if as the continuation or no. Thank you to help me!

Comment: where is youer css file?
Path For JS::View/Frontend/Web/Js
Path For Css::View/Frontend/Web/Css

Comment: for the css file I put it in view/adminhtml/web/css

Comment: run  this  comand :: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Or youcan can check your formate
  $this->addColumn(
            'product_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Select Product'),
                'sortable' => false,
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'field_name' => 'product_id[]',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );

Comment: Label is display properly?

Comment: i change it css under view /Frontend /web/css, not yet apparently he does not even read the file css

Comment: I run this comand  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy   but it appears an error: NOTE: Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "de  
  veloper" modes.                                                              
  In "default" and "developer" modes static contents are being deployed autom  
  atically on demand.                                                          
  If you still want to deploy in these modes, use -f option: 'bin/magento set  
  up:static-content:deploy -f'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71523/discussion-between-birjitsinh-zala-and-lisa).

Answer (score 0):

Store your Css in

> App/Code/Vendor/Module/View/Location/Web/css

Ans Store js in

> App/Code/Vendor/Module/View/Location/Web/js

in your layout

```
<!-- for css file -->
   <css src="Vendor_Module::css/grid.css"/>

   <!-- for js file -->
   <script src="Vendor_Module::js/grid.js"/>
```

then run comand => `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: I run this comand php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy but it appears an error: NOTE: Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "de veloper" modes. In "default" and "developer" modes static contents are being deployed autom atically on demand. If you still want to deploy in these modes, use -f option: 'bin/magento set up:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: no problem youcan use bin/magento set up:static-content:deploy -f 
and  your path is right view/adminhtml/web/css don change